# NPM installation Error - "Python is not set from command line or npm configuration" for fibers installation using @wdio/sync

Tags: python, synchronization, fibers, wdio, wdiosync

There is an issue while doing npm install for @wdio/sync.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@wdio/sync@7.16.10 is using a inner dependency of "fibers" npm which is causing to install the python on the machine.

fibers is using the threading for node application which was running nodejs < 13.x. After Node14.x has incorporated  the threading module in core and now fibers package is depricating itself from Node14.x and not support onwards. Fibers will only work with Node <=12.

Fibers team has released a new patch as "fibers@5.0.2" which is breaking with Node<=14.x.
[image]

To fix the issue use **"fibers@5.0.1"** instead of 5.0.2 for Nodejs <=14.x